# I can't reinstalling java: newer version of java found message pops up

Tags: java, installation

Im quite a newbies, this is what happen. For the first time, i installed jdk 8 to run jaspersoft ETL. after doing some development, i want to test run the ETL build on a server but it seems that the server is using the java 6 so i can't run it. Even a simple java program like hello world can't be executed (if compile with IDE using jre8). i can't install java 6 on the server since they wont give me permission. so im using the java compliance level setting to rebuild the ETL. i installed jdk 6 into my computer and configure the compliance level but it seems that whatever i do, the program wont build. so i figured there is maybe a conflict between java 6 and java 8 on my computer.

(here is actually my problem)

So i uninstall all the java version i have using the traditional control panel method. then i reinstall jdk 6 but during installation a message pops up saying "newer version of java already found" (something like that). i check on my Program Files/Java folder under C:, only jdk folder exist but no jre. i try uninstall and install it again but still have the same issue. Why do it keep saying that theres already a newer version of java found when im already have uninstall everything.

I already remove the registry using this method: https://java.com/en/download/help/manual_regedit.xml
but still got the same issue

Answer (score 0):

The version is still exist because your operating system using it.

Comment: but i already uninstalled it. how do i completely remove the java

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. i install the troubleshooting software from microsoft for this kind of issue. got it from here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed